# Webpack building the wrong file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

So I've a bug I've been chasing all day, and I've narrowed it down to my webpack config (*I think*).

- I run my app locally using `webpack server` and `index.html` is displayed correctly (with the relevant script file).
- I build my project locally, right-click `index.html` and open with `live-server`, and `index.html` is displayed correctly
- I upload my files to my server, get `Express` to return `index.html`, and it returns `index.html` (I can tell because the script tag refers to `index.js` and the `title` tab says home), but the content is that of `admin.html`

Deleting the contents of `index.html` on the server to a simple page confirms (imo) that it isn't an issue of `Express` serving the wrong file

So it must be a webpack issue, right?

What I don't understand is why `webpack server` and `live server` display the content correctly, but the (apparently) same file doesn't in production. I probably don't have the correct `webpack.prod.js` config settings (they're basically empty), but I'm not experienced enough to spot the issue, so would appreciate if someone has the time to look

My file structure locally:

```
|-dist
|
|-src
|  |-- assets
|  |-- css
|  |-- js
|  |-- admin.html
|  |-- index.html
|  
|-webpack.common.js
|-webpack.dev.js
|-webpack.prod.js
|-package.json
|-// more config files
```

// webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/js/controllers/indexController.js',
        admin: './src/js/controllers/adminController.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.css$/i,
                use:  ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/i,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
             },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html',
            chunks: ['index']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'admin.html',
            template: './src/admin.html',
            chunks: ['admin']
        })
    ]
}
```

// webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
        port: 4600,
        open: {
            app: {
              name: 'chrome',
            },
          },
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchFiles: ["src/**/*"]
    },  
    
});
```

// webpack.prod.js

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');


module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
});
```

---

***Edit** I still think the server is sending the correct `html` file because the `title` and `js` src reference `index`, however the source now does look wrong (it has been correct in the past):

// var/www/my-site/express-app/public/html/index.html

`<script defer="defer" src="./src/js/controllers/index.bundle.0bb3ac28e5969d907928.js"></script>`

But I've no idea why the file was previously displaying another page's html (despite me removing that page, `admin.html`, entirely). It's no longer doing that, just complaining about the path to the file - which is progress.

[image]

Server file structure

```
// var/www/my-site/express-app

|-node_modules
|
|-public
|  |-- assets
|  |-- css
|  |-- js
|  |-- admin.html
|  |-- index.html
|  
|-package-lock.json
|-package.json
|-app.js
```

// app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/index', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('path:', path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('path:', path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});


app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).json({msg: 'Please contact your web administrator'});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Can u pls show express res.sendFile code?

Comment: cab you also add correct `publicPath:""` to the `output` propery of webpack

Comment: @Yilmaz Will add both now, but I've changed the `index.html` file's contents and it's definitely displaying it.

Comment: `publicPath:"correctPathHeretoJs"`

Comment: @Yilmaz, just added, but now my local build isn't working and the file on the server has a 404/MIME type ('text/html') error

Comment: your output files are in `dist` but express is serving from public? do you manually copy the output fles to the public

Comment: why dont you just have express serve from dist

Comment: I did try, but I struggled to work out how to organise my files correctly - my webpack config just dumped them all in the same folder, and attempting to change the paths led to more errors/I got advice just to move it to a separate folder. I was on a tightish deadline for a friend and I've historically lost fights with webpack :) I'd really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction, it would make my life much easier to have it all served from dist